# A message body writer for java.util.ArrayList and Java type java.util.List<entities.UserEntity> and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, json, jersey, mime

I'm trying to get a web service to work which returns a JSON. The goal is to display all the elements of my SQL database. However, I get the exception below. I have looked at the similar problems but none of the solutions work for me.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Error :

```
28-Nov-2021 15:48:45.769 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
28-Nov-2021 15:48:46.028 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.7.Final
28-Nov-2021 15:48:46.703 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.244 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.261 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_atos]
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.263 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.263 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.275 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init> HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
28-Nov-2021 15:48:47.858 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
28-Nov-2021 15:48:49.872 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
28-Nov-2021 15:48:50.119 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<entities.UserEntity>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

28-Nov-2021 15:48:50.120 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
    javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<entities.UserEntity>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<entities.UserEntity>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

        ... 30 more
```

UserEntity file :

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "test_atos")
public class UserEntity {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private Date birthday;
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private String gender;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false)
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = 20)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = true)
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (username != null ? !username.equals(that.username) : that.username != null) return false;
        if (birthday != null ? !birthday.equals(that.birthday) : that.birthday != null) return false;
        if (country != null ? !country.equals(that.country) : that.country != null) return false;
        if (phone != null ? !phone.equals(that.phone) : that.phone != null) return false;
        if (gender != null ? !gender.equals(that.gender) : that.gender != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (birthday != null ? birthday.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (country != null ? country.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (gender != null ? gender.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

UserRESTAPI file :

```
package atos.api;

import entities.UserEntity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/user")
public class UserRESTAPI {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("")

    public List<UserEntity> getAll(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        List<UserEntity> u = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user", UserEntity.class).getResultList();
        return u;
    }
}
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>userAtosAPI</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>userAtosAPI</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

persistance.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
  <persistence-unit name="default">

    <class>entities.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_atos"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>atos.api</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>truc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
<!-- end snippet -->

hibernate.cfg.xml file

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_atos</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="entities.UserEntity"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It may be because your Jersey versions don't match. You use `1.19.2` for `jersey-bundle`, `jersey-server`, and `jersey-core`, but `1.8` for `jersey-json`.

Comment: I checked but it doesn't seem like it

Comment: Do you get the same exception?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same here, @Plikplak did you find a solution?
In my case this is only happening on a Production environment but not locally.